# Importing a daily file with variable name into access database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Let me apologize in advance if this question has been posed somewhere and I overlooked it. I've spent multiple days on this and cannot get it to run 100%.

I am trying to import an excel file that gets sent via email every morning into an access database. The file has a date portion that changes every day. The naming follows the same pattern everyday of "FTTQ m-dd-yyyy". The day shown in the file name is for the previous work day, ex. receive email on 8/25 for FTTQ on 8/24. The code below is what I have so far and it will loop through the folder, however when it reaches the correct day it cannot find it. I have tried a couple variations but Access keeps crashing when I try to run it. Ideally I need Access to find the latest date on the file and import it, such as coming in on Monday and getting the file for Friday/Saturday or during the week getting it for the day before. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
Dim strToday As String
Dim strFilePath as String
Dim strFile as String

strToday = Format(Date, "m-dd-yyyy")
strFilePath = "C:\Users\cole.stratton\Documents\Procurement\FTTQ 'Note:FTTQ is the beginning of the file name
strFile = Dir(strFilePath, "*.xlsx")

  Do While strFile <> ""
    If Right(strFile,14) = strToday & ".xlsx" Then
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, acImport, "tblTest",strFile, True
    End If
  strFile = Dir 'Note: I do not understand the point of this line or what it does or supposed to do.
  Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the latest existing file, I would change the loop like this:

```vb
Dim searchDate As Date
Dim strDate As String
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Long

' Search backwards from today for a file with the date name
For i = 0 To -7 Step -1
    searchDate = DateAdd("d", i, Date)
    strDate = Format(searchDate, "m-dd-yyyy")
    strFilePath = "C:\Users\cole.stratton\Documents\Procurement\FTTQ " & strDate & ".xlsx"
    Debug.Print "Looking for: " & strFilePath 
    ' Check if file exists
    strFile = Dir(strFilePath)
    If strFile <> "" Then
        ' Note that Dir() only returns the file name, so use strFilePath
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tblTest", strFilePath, True
        ' file found, exit loop
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I tried this and when it ran I got Runtime Error 3170: Could not find installable ISAM

Comment: What happens if you remove the comma from between `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` and `acImport`?

Comment: I removed it and now get a type mismatch error on that line it happens for `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, "tblTest", strFilePath, True` and `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, "tblTest", strFile, True`.

Comment: The second argument for `TransferSpreadsheet` should be a value from the *AcSpreadSheetType Enumeration*, but that code is giving it *TableName* ... which should be the *third* argument to `TransferSpreadsheet`.  Check the *DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method* topic in Access' built-in help system from details.

Comment: Completely forgot about that part. Now it is added back in. It's almost there but now Access is looking for the file in the `Documents` folder instead of going to `Documents\Procurement` to find it. Runtime Error: 3011: Could not find the object `C:\Users\cole.stratton\Documents\FTTQ 8-24-2015`.

Comment: Hmm?  Set a breakpoint, run the code and use F8 to step through the code one line at a time and monitor the value of *strFilePath*.

Comment: Edited: corrected DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet parameters (should have checked that), and added a debug output (goes to the Immediate Window - press Ctrl+g). I can see no reason why it would look in the wrong folder. Unless the path is wrong, then it might default to "My documents".

Comment: That was my mistake on that one and I resolved it. Thank you @HansUp for your support. Now just need to get the person sending the email to fix their headers so access will accept it every time and I will be in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

***I'm assuming that you have the closing " in your strFilePath line in your actual code. ****

This line looks like the issue...

`strFile = Dir(strFilePath, "*.xlsx")`

This page will show you the correct syntax for using Dir...http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php

`strFile = Dir(strFilePath & "*.xlsx")` <-- you were putting the file extension in where the attributes were supposed to go.

However, you also need to change your date.  If the file will have yesterday's date, not today's...`strToday = Format(Date-1, "m-dd-yyyy")`

This line...
`strFile = Dir`

sets your string to the next file name that meets your search criteria.

Comment: How would I account for coming in on Monday and finding a file for 2-3 days ago? While yes that would work for finding yesterday, there will never be a file that gets saved with a Sunday date, in this case 8/23. I would need it to find 8/21 or 8/22.

Comment: I corrected the mistake and made the changes suggested but get the same runtime error as with the other answer. Runtime Error 3170: Could not find installable ISAM

Comment: @ColeStratton Please explain the logic Access can use to know whether to check for a filename which contains yesterday's date vs. some other earlier date.  Also is it possible that your *Button1_Click* procedure could ever be run twice on the same day?  If so, what should happen then?

Comment: There should be no reason for the button to be clicked more than once per day. As of now do not know what to do if it does happen. Let me provide an example that may help, today received email for FTTQ 8-21-2015. As this is not yesterday, I still need to get that file imported into the database.

Comment: But since today's date is 8-24-2015, how can Access know you want it to look for 8-21-2015 instead of 8-22-2015 or 8-23-2015?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to move each FTTQ<date>.xlsx file from the Procurement folder to an Archive folder after it's been imported?  Then, the task requirement could be simpler ... "if there is an FTTQ<date>.xlsx in the Procurement folder, import it".

Comment: That would make more sense and it sounds a lot simpler. Is there a question already asked related to this otherwise I will ask another because I do not know how to move files from folder to folder within Access

Comment: `Name "old full filepath here" As "new full filepath here"`  like this ... `Name "C:\share\Access\temp.xlsx" As "C:\share\Access\Archive\temp.xlsx"`

Comment: Sorry, I was distracted by another project.  Looks like you might have gotten this all worked out anyway.